# TTY's cursor moves to wrong position during login

Tags: startup, tty, prompt, cursor, ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 without a desktop manager.

When my system is started, it goes to tty0, and the screen appears like this:

```
<my-pc-name> login: |
```

where `|` represents the cursor. 
After a few seconds my cursor shifts to the beginning of line like this:

```
|<my-pc-name> login:
```

I can login "normally", but
when I type my username, the new text overwrites all text to the right of the cursor (i.e., the login prompt).

When I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to switch to tty1, this problem has not happened.

How can I debug this?

Comment: `host-login:` _is_ your prompt when logging in.  It cannot shift to before itself.  Are you mistakenly using the word "prompt" for your _cursor_?  Or are you mistakenly referring to login when in fact the behaviour observed is _after login_, in your shell?

Comment: If you login and logout, do you still have the same problem the second time?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: P.S. When you [edit] your question, please use edit summaries that describe what you changed.  Don't say "edited format" when you really updated the information. And don't add annotations like "Update"; just fix the post so it looks like what it should have been from the beginning.

Comment: Ubuntu Server 16.04 does that. It does it only once after boot, and only in the first virtual console. It is a simple cosmetic defect. Let it be; wait a little until it does it, press Enter to get a new prompt, and forget about it.

Comment: Thank you @AlexP ! I though it was a hardware error or an unproper config of mine.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question on how to debug this, here is what I have tried:

I wrote a low tech script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
        DATE=`date +%H%M%S`
        ps -e f > pss.out/$DATE
        echo -ne '\n'$DATE
        sleep 1
done
```

When the system boots up, I quickly log in and run the script.
I watched until I saw a line of output disappear, and then diffed the ps output from before and after the event.

```
user@ubuntu-back:~/pss.out$ diff 080234 080236
108d107
<   776 ?        Ss     0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-fsckd
138c137
<  1630 tty1     R+     0:00          \_ ps -e f
---
>  1634 tty1     R+     0:00          \_ ps -e f
user@ubuntu-back:~/pss.out$
```

so I could see that the systemd-fsckd was somehow responsible.

To prove it, I turned off file system checking in my fstab, and the problem went away.

Obviously that isn't the actual fix, but it is all I have so far.

In my case I need to figure this out because I have been tasked with having a system that automatically starts a text based app (that I didn't write) on startup, and this problem creates screen artifacts.

Comment: Thank you for this - I thought I was going mad. Did you ever resolve?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by systemd-fsck printing `'\r'` to `/dev/console`. The terminal tty1 thus must wait until systemd-fsckd is inactive. My preliminary fix on my Ubuntu 18.04.4 system involves a file `/etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/override.conf`:

```
[Unit]
After=boot-efi.mount
After=systemd-fsckd.service

[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/usr/local/bin/delaytty1.sh $TERM
Type=idle
```

The script /usr/local/bin/delaytty1.sh reads:

```
#!/bin/sh
a="active"
while [ $a = "active" ]; do
sleep 1
a=$(/bin/systemctl is-active systemd-fsckd.service)
done
/sbin/agetty --noclear tty1 $1
```